# Deleting Mode Analytics Bridge Connector

Tags: mysql, sql, bridge, mode-analytics

After installing the Mode Analytics Bridge Connector for a remote MySQL database I decided to use another type of connection.

I installed [this](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mode-distribution/public/release/mode-bridge/osx/ModeBridge-Latest.pkg) `.pkg` and ran this code:

```
/usr/local/mode/bin/mode-bridge-config -init OGU2NGNmYWUxOWFmOjQxYmZhZDhmOWM5ZGRlNGE3Nzk1OTYyYUBodHRwczovL21vZGVhbmFseXRpY3MuY29tL2FwaS9kb21lZGlhL2JyaWRnZXMvc2V0dXA=
```

from [this](https://modeanalytics.com/domedia/data_sources/bridges/setup/default/mysql?flow=select_source) page, which won't load without an account with Mode.

Now I want to **completely** remove everything installed by that `.pkg` and undo everything done by that code.

I already removed `.modeanalytics`.  What else should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the Mode Analytics Bridge on OSX is a bit of work because Apple doesn't provide a way to remove packages installed with their installer.  You need to remove more than the `.modeanalytics` directory.

Here are the steps needed:

1. ```sh
   launchctl stop com.modeanalytics.bridge
   ```
2. ```sh
   launchctl unload $HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.modeanalytics.bridge.plist
   ```
3. ```sh
   rm -rf $HOME/.modeanalytics/*
   ```
4. ```sh
   rm -rf /usr/local/mode
   ```
5. ```sh
   rm /var/db/receipts/com.modeanalytics.mode-bridge.bom
   ```
6. ```sh
   rm /var/db/receipts/com.modeanalytics.mode-bridge.plist
   ```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you!